# How to use pivottabler package to get sum instead of count

Tags: r, function, sum, pivot, render

[Excel pivot function to change count to sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjrmD.png)#Using pivottabler package in r

#### In Excel pivots, value field settings allow a change from count to Sum.  Using code from CBailiss that was posted in this forum on a subset of the inbuilt data set, bhmtrains, this code generates a pivot table but the sum is no different from the count.[pivot generated by this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqXex.png)  [pivot in Excel to generate in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zw8E.png)

```
library(pivottabler)
```

### function by CBAILISS

```
getPercentageOfAllCategories <- function(pivotCalculator, netFilters, format, baseValues, cell) {
trains <- pivotCalculator$getDataFrame("bhmtrainsSub")
netFilters$setFilterValues(variableName="TrainCategory", type="ALL", values=NULL, action="replace") 
filteredTrains <- pivotCalculator$getFilteredDataFrame(trains, netFilters)
totalTrainsAllCategories <- nrow(filteredTrains)
percentageOfAllCategories <- baseValues$N / totalTrainsAllCategories * 100
value <- list()
value$rawValue <- percentageOfAllCategories
value$formattedValue <- pivotCalculator$formatValue(percentageOfAllCategories, format=format)
return(value)
```

}

### sum function that returns count - seeking a fix or a better solution

```
getSumOfAllCategories <- function(pivotCalculator, netFilters, format, baseValues, cell) {
trains <- pivotCalculator$getDataFrame("bhmtrainsSub")
netFilters$setFilterValues(variableName="TrainCategory", type="ALL", values=NULL, action="replace") 
filteredTrains <- pivotCalculator$getFilteredDataFrame(trains, netFilters)
totalTrainsAllCategories <- nrow(filteredTrains)
SumOfAllCategories <- sum(baseValues$N)
value <- list()
value$rawValue <- SumOfAllCategories
value$formattedValue <- pivotCalculator$formatValue(SumOfAllCategories, format=format)
return(value)
```

}

### Create a subset of bhmtrains inbuilt data set

```
bhmtrainsdf <- bhmtrains[c(3:6)]
bhmtrainsSub <- bhmtrainsdf[0:500, ]
```

### create and render the pivot

```
    pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(bhmtrainsSub) 
pt$addColumnDataGroups("PowerType")
pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC")
pt$addRowDataGroups("TrainCategory")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="N", summariseExpression="n()")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Percentage", caption="%", format="%.1f %%", basedOn="N", type="function", calculationFunction=getPercentageOfAllCategories)
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Sum", caption="SUM", basedOn="N", type="function", calculationFunction=getSumOfAllCategories)
pt$renderPivot()
```

Answer (score 0):

## An elegant solution is provided in package rpivotTable

#### needs installation of package ‘htmlwidgets’ that does not have to be called explicitly)

#### provides a good solve for what I sought but I intended to use the data from the pivot in further computations

#### [pivot in R with sums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSWIW.png)

library(rpivotTable) 
    rpivotTable(bhmtrainsSub, rows=c("TOC","TrainCategory"), cols="PowerType",width="100%", height="400px")

Answer (score 0):

To sum, alter the defineCalculation call, e.g.

```
library(pivottabler)
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(bhmtrains) 
pt$addColumnDataGroups("TrainCategory")
pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalMPH",
                     summariseExpression="sum(SchedSpeedMPH, na.rm=TRUE)")
pt$renderPivot()
```

Similarly, for a mean:

```
library(pivottabler)
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(bhmtrains) 
pt$addColumnDataGroups("TrainCategory")
pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="MeanMPH", 
                     summariseExpression="mean(SchedSpeedMPH, na.rm=TRUE)", format="%.1f")
pt$renderPivot()
```

Much more information be found at:
http://pivottabler.org.uk/articles/v01-introduction.html

There are many examples within the website, e.g. more on calculations at:
http://pivottabler.org.uk/articles/v03-calculations.html

Hope that helps

Chris